# Old hostname still seen after fresh install of a completely different distro

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

Something strange happened when I installed Fedora on an SSD that previously had ubuntu installed on it.

Essentially, the hostname was configured to be ubuntupc, so when I opened the terminal, I'd get this screen:

```
nasser@ubuntupc:
```

After I installed Fedora on that drive, on top of the ubuntu install, the prompt also read `nasser@ubuntupc:`. How did this happen?!

Comment: Probably your home router remembered that as the hostname your Ubuntu installation advertised for your device, and Fedora picked it back up from there as default. Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/800844/367990

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the contents of the `/etc/hostname` file and the output of the `hostnamectl status` command.

Comment: I've changed the hostname since then, but I was just curious as to what may have happened. Thanks for your response, though!

Comment: @ByteCommander seems like a reasonable explanation, I did connect to my home internet before opening the first terminal session.